# OpenVPN server accepting connections but not allowing traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a rooted Android box with Linux Deploy to make it a OpenVPN server. I have diligently followed the guide at https://nanashi07.blogspot.com/2017/...id-device.html and the one at https://www.digitalocean.com/communi...n-ubuntu-16-04 and I have used keys and certificates that do work correctly on a Windows server.

The OpenVPN client connects correctly to the server, but at that point it can't go outside. In facts, the only thing I managed to do from the client is ping 10.8.0.6 which is its own IP assigned by the VPN server, can't even ping the server itself. After studying a lot and spending 2 days playing around with configuration, I have come to the conclusion that I need to ask for some help. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

In particular, some things that I did (as I see they are often reason for a problem similar to mine) are:
modifying the /etc/sysctl.conf file, uncommenting

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

modified /etc/ufw/before.rules with

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

modified the the /etc/default/ufw with

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

and I also changed the default input policy to "Accept" for now, this was not required but should not be the cause of my problem.

The openvpn server configuration is

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Ifconfig now reads

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:2a:fe:48:63:81
          inet addr:192.168.0.174  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c62a:feff:fe48:6381/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:997126 (997.1 KB)  TX bytes:1110696 (1.1 MB)
          Interrupt:56

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00                      -00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:200 (200.0 B)
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Many Thanks!